# unable to perform increment in python loop

Tags: python, for-loop, networking

This is to print ip's in the range of /28 subnet (which are 16 IP's) and I'm only getting 1 as output.
I have the actual output for this code and the expected so that i can understand this better, kindly let me know what is the correction i have to do here.

```
givenIp = '192.168.2.0/28'
subNet = givenIp.split('/')
ip = subNet[0]
subNetMask = subNet[1]

def totalNoOfHosts(NetMask):

    hosts = (32 - int(NetMask)) * 4
    return hosts

NoOfHost = totalNoOfHosts(subNetMask)

def ipInRange(baseIp):
    print('Number of hosts:' + str(NoOfHost))
    splitIP = baseIp.split('.')
    fourthOctet = splitIP[3]
    for i in str(NoOfHost):
        fourthOctet = int(fourthOctet) + 1
        splitIP[3] = fourthOctet
        newIp = splitIP
        print(newIp)
        return newIp
```

Output:

```
Number of hosts:16
['192', '168', '2', 1]
```

Expected Output:

```
['192', '168', '2', 1] 
['192', '168', '2', 2]
['192', '168', '2', 3]
.
.
.
.
['192', '168', '2', 16]
```

Comment: Is there a requirement you do this on your own? There is an entire library for IPv4 and IPv6, builtin. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Comment: You are `return`ing in your loop; it will never get past that. Also you probably don't want to iterate over the string `str(NoOfHost)` — maybe `range(NoOfHost)`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer is right. Remove the `return` statement and change `str(NoOfHost)` to `range(NoOfHost)`.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind code is correct, however you have done 2 mistakes that are explained below:

1. Taking the str(NoOfHost) in the loop will not iterate the value for the number of times as the value is of string type. So change it to the range function that is range(0, NoOfHost).
2. The second error is of Indentation of the return statement in the for loop. as return statement has to be part of function and as it is in for loop, it leads the function to en its execution thus executing the loop just once. 
   (Indentation in Python refers to the (spaces and tabs) that are used at the beginning of a statement.)
   Refer the code below:

```
    givenIp = '192.168.2.0/28'
    subNet = givenIp.split('/')
    ip = subNet[0]
    subNetMask = subNet[1]

    def totalNoOfHosts(NetMask):

        hosts = (32 - int(NetMask)) * 4
        return hosts

    NoOfHost = totalNoOfHosts(subNetMask)

    def ipInRange(baseIp):
        print('Number of hosts:' + str(NoOfHost))
        splitIP = baseIp.split('.')
        fourthOctet = splitIP[3]
        for i in range(0, NoOfHost):
            fourthOctet = int(fourthOctet) + 1
            splitIP[3] = fourthOctet
            newIp = splitIP
            print(newIp)
        return newIp
    latestIp = ipInRange(ip)
    print("Last IP returned by the function is : ",latestIp)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are not required to perform this work yourself, you can use the `ipaddress` module built into Python. It makes tasks such as the one you're trying to achieve very simple.

```
import ipaddress

list(ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.10.0/30').hosts())
#[IPv4Address('192.168.10.1'), IPv4Address('192.168.10.2')]
```

However, to achieve what you're trying to do in your question you can do the follow;

Note, this isnt efficient and will not work on say a /8 or /16 subnet as you're relying on modifying only the 4th octet. I would highly recommend you just use the ipaddress module.

```
def ipInRange(baseIp):
    count = int(baseIp.split('.')[3]) + 1
    addresses = []
    for i in range(NoOfHost):
        ip = baseIp.split('.')
        ip[3] = str(count)
        ip = '.'.join(ip)
        count += 1

        addresses.append(ip)

    return addresses

print(ipInRange(ip))
```